# Dynamic TabPanels with nested listviews (having dynamic items) asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, tabcontrol

I have TabControl(AjaxToolKit) having 2 Nested ListViews.

code:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TabContainer ID="tcQuestions" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"    OnDemand="true" AutoPostBack="false" TabStripPlacement="Top" ScrollBars="None" UseVerticalStripPlacement="false">
        <asp:TabPanel ID="tpFirst" runat="server" HeaderText="Page 1" Enabled="true" ScrollBars="Auto"
            OnDemandMode="Once">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlNoData" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbQuestionsAdd" Text="Add Question" runat="server" />    
                </asp:Panel>

                <asp:Panel ID="pnlListView" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListView ID="lsvQuestions" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="phItemPlaceHoler">
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <em>NO RECORD WAS FOUND</em>                            
                       </EmptyDataTemplate>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionID" Text='<%#Eval("intQuesId") %>' Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionTitle" Text='<%#Eval("strQuesTitle") %>' runat="server" />
                                    <%--1.Are you doing job?--%>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <%--Inner Listview--%>
                            <asp:ListView ID="lsvAnswers" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="phItemPlaceHolerAnswers">
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <table runat="server" id="table1">
                                        <tr runat="server" id="phItemPlaceHolerAnswers">
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plControl" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <em>NO RECORD WAS FOUND</em>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>                            
                       </ItemTemplate>
                       <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table class="tblAll">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 125px">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAddQuestions" runat="server">Add Questions</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 316px">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDesignTools" runat="server">Design Tools</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="formTopLinks">
                                            <img class="imgicons" src="../Layout/images/edit.png" />
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEditProperties" runat="server" CssClass="lnkbuttonText">Edit Properties</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="formTopLinks">
                                            <img class="imgicons" src="../Layout/images/Delete.png" />
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCopyPage" runat="server" CssClass="lnkbuttonText">Copy Page</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="formTopLinks">
                                            <img class="imgicons" src="../Layout/images/Copy.png" />
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDeletePage" runat="server" CssClass="lnkbuttonText">Delete Page</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 20px;">
                                            <img class="imgicons" src="../Layout/images/left.png" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 64px;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="lnkbuttonText" Text="Move Page" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 20px;">
                                            <img class="imgicons" src="../Layout/images/right.png" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            &#160;
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <br />
                            <table class="tblAll">
                                <tbody>
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phItemPlaceHoler" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>                            
                       </LayoutTemplate>
                  </asp:ListView>    
              </asp:Panel>                   
          </ContentTemplate>            
      </asp:TabPanel>
  </asp:TabContainer>
```

Where, I am getting Question from Table "Question", and its answers from another table "Answers". Each Question is linked with a `PageNumber`.

so, i have to create `TabPanels` according to `PageNumber` from Question, Then Bind Question Label with that Question, and fill 2nd `ListView` with Answers of that Question.

These answers are dynamic controls based on db entries e.g `textbox`, `checkboxlists`, `radiobutton lists` and may vary for every question.

Now what i am doing is copying tabPanel 1 to new `TabPanel` and adding question and answers according to db values, but when i am creating 2nd `TabPanel`, it give me error that

```
Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'ContentPlaceHolder1_tcQuestions_tpFirst_updatePanel' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager. This might occur if the UpdatePanel was removed from the control tree and later added again, which is not supported.
```

What is the best approach to handle this scenerio.

something like [SurverMonkey](http://www.surveymonkey.com/) except i am using tabs for new page.